# For post deployment/upgrade testing in kubernetes, what is the best trigger for the tests

Tags: kubernetes

I am adding end-to-end tests to our dev env which is in kubernetes.  I'd like to kick off tests whenever a service is updated.  My question is: what is the best way to kick off tests when a new/updated service is ready.

I have found two options that seem ok, but not perfect:

1) [post-upgrade helm chart hooks](https://helm.sh/docs/charts_hooks/#the-available-hooks)

2) [validating admission webhooks](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/03/21/a-guide-to-kubernetes-admission-controllers/)

Does anyone have experience in this regard or an opinion on the best way?  Is there another way that I have missed?

EDIT:
After suggesting admission webhooks to my devops team, they pointed me to kubernetes controllers and I found this:

https://github.com/bitnami-labs/kubewatch

I think that kubewatch will meet my needs.

Comment: Can you give more details and post some examples? Also, can you explain better why these options are not matching to your needs? Why are you considering helm hooks? If possible, edit your question with these information.

Comment: @mWatney please see my update.  I think that I found a solution if my devops team accepts it.